# What is User define function and how to execute that?

Tags: sql-server-2005

What is user define function in sql server 2005.How Can I see them from design point of view.
I wanted to create and execute the function.Can anybody explain me.I have not  done it before.

Comment: You're looking for the documentation.

Comment: See [Intro to user-defined functions](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/intro-to-user-defined-functions-updated) or **many many more** links when you search on Google....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[User-Defined Functions from MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189593%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)